# How to use inline styles to use transform: rotate() with react.js on scroll

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Creating this page. I have an element I want to rotate on scroll. Would prefer to use react syntax to create this 'animation'.

```
LeftGear = () =>  {
const rotate = window.scrollY / 10 % Math.PI

const divStyle = {
  backgroundColor: 'purple',
  transform: `scroll(${rotate})`,
}

return  <img
          className={this.changeClassName('circleImage')}
          src="../../assets/icons/red-gear.svg"
          alt="Circles Icon"
          style={divStyle}
        />
}

render(){
  return <LeftGear/>  
}
```

this works to give the image a background but does not work for that scroll. So Im wondering what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Shouldn't you add the "rotate" and "deg"? [rotate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/rotate)

Answer (score 1):

Rotations work with `transform: rotate({n}deg)` where `{n}` is your radius number. For the rest, bind and event listener to the window in an useEffect hook. Instead of updating the `divStyle` object, just create a reference to the image and update the `style.transform` property.

React has no *smart* way of dealing with this, so sometimes you just have to use some vanilla JS.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

const LeftGear = () => {
  const imageRef = useRef();
  const divStyle = {
    backgroundColor: 'purple',
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', event => {
      requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        const rotation = window.scrollY / 10 % Math.PI;
        imageRef.current.style.transform = `rotate(${rotation}deg)`;
      });
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <img
      ref={imageRef}
      className={this.changeClassName('circleImage')}
      src="../../assets/icons/red-gear.svg"
      alt="Circles Icon"
      style={divStyle}
    />
  )
}
```

Comment: thank you for the response the issue was the transition value, :) should of used rotate of course. tried your solution but wasnt able to use 'useRef' it was undefined, idk. thanks again

Comment: `useRef` and `useEffect` are hooks from React that should be imported. I've added an import statement above.